# The pagination in wordpress not work correctly

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with pagination for the custom post. I used these code bellow for my site:
The content still show content on loop are correct but when I click next number, it still in first page without jumpping to  the next page.
How to fix this issues ?

````
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => 'nha-dat-binh-duong',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged
    ) );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <!-- begin loop -->
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            GET CONTENT HERE
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end loop -->


        <div class="pagination">
            <?php 
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                'show_all'     => false,
                'type'         => 'plain',
                'end_size'     => 2,
                'mid_size'     => 1,
                'prev_next'    => true,
                'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Tin mới nhất', 'text-domain' ) ),
                'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( '⏩', 'text-domain' ) ),
                'add_args'     => false,
                'add_fragment' => '',
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>```
````

Answer (score -1):

Have you refreshed your permalinks? Simply go to permalinks in WordPress and then refresh the page.